# Prove that if m is an integer and there is a rational number r/s so that (r/s)^2 = m, then there is an integer n so that n^2 = m.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I recognize that a rational number a/b means that b does not divide a and also that a and b are relatively prime. Does that mean rational numbers are always expressed in their simplest form? Or is my statement about coprime wrong?

I have tried using Euclid's Algorithm and Bezout's Identity, since that is the section that the question comes from but I have not gotten it to work out.

Please Help.

Comment: This is a huge FAQ, e.g. see the linked dupe (and its links) for *many* methods of proving this well-known theorem that if $\sqrt{m}\,$ is rational then it is an integer (or, equivalently, if $m$ is not an exact square then $\,\sqrt{m}\,$ is irrational), e.g. it is a special case of the Rational Root Test.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Write your rational number as an irreducible fraction ($\gcd(r,s)=1$),  use that
$$\Bigl(\frac{r}{s}\Bigr)^2=m \iff r^2=ms^2$$
and deduce with Gauß' lemma that $s=1$.

Comment: I do not know what Gauss' Lemma is, we have not covered it in class. I have looked it up too but I think my proof is suppose to use Bezout's Identity, Euclid's Algorithm and the division theorem.

Comment: Gauß' lemma asserts that if $n$ divides $ab$ and $n$ is coprime to $a$, then $n$ divides $b$. And precisely, its proof uses *Bézout's identity*.